# Usar request.getAttribute("key"))

Tags: servlet

Estou passando uma lista List e quero recuperar no jsp através do request.getAttribute("key"):

```
@Override
protected doGet(HTTPServlet request, HTTPServletResponse response)
   throw new ServletException {

  List<Hotel> hotel=Hotel.listar();
  request.setAttribute("key", hoteis);

  RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("./hotel/exibe_hoteis.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

No jsp eu faço:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa Tarde André Nascimento,

Para recuperar a lista no atributo `request.getAttribute();` existem duas formas.

- Utilizando scriptlets
- Utilizando o framework JSTL

**Utilizando Scriptlets**

Seu código vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<% List hoteis = (List) request.getAttribute("key"); %>
```

*Neste momento você já terá acesso aos hoteis através da variável `hoteis`.*
Dai basta iterar todos os hoteis dentro de um for e exibi-los para o usuário.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>Nome do hotel</th>
      <th>Preço da estadia</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <% for(int i = 0; i < hoteis.size(); i++) {%>
       <tr>
        <td><%= hoteis.get(i).getNomeHotel() %></td>
        <td><%= hoteis.get(i).getPrecoEstadia() %></td>
       </tr>
       <%}%>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

*Estou assumindo que sua classe hotel possui os atributos:
 **nomeHotel** e **precoEstadia**, por isso inclui no código, mas você pode utilizar seus próprios atributos.*

**Utilizando o framework JSTL**

Para rodar um laço `for` dentro do **JSTL** você utiliza a tag `<c:forEach></c:forEach>`

Seu código vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>Nome do hotel</th>
      <th>Preço da estadia</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <c:forEach items="${requestScope.hoteis}" var="hotel">
       <tr>
        <td>
          ${hotel.nomeHotel}
        </td>
        <td>
         ${hotel.precoEstadia}
        </td>
       </tr>
      </c:forEach>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

*Pronto, dessa forma você conseguirá exibir todos os itens normalmente.*

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: adicionei a linha: <% List hoteis = (List) request.getAttribute("key"); %>
, como faço para importar o util.List?

Comment: consegui coloquei <%@ page import="java.util.List" %> valeu, grato. Vou fazer com as dus alternativas para aprender.

Comment: Ok, que bom que conseguiu.
Se tudo der certo, não se esqueça de marcar a questão como correta para ajudar outras pessoas também.